# How to get difference between to DateTime in php?

Tags: php, time

Suppose I have this code:

```
$log_in = "2015-9-16 07:00:00";
$log_out = "2015-9-16 20:00:00";
$diff = $log_out-$log_in;
```

The answer should be: 13:00 (hh:mm)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the DateTime Object

```
$x = new DateTime("2015-9-16 07:00:00");
$y = new DateTime("2015-9-16 20:00:00");
$diff = $x->diff($y);
```

more info can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

edit: if you need diff for humans you can use [carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/)

Comment: can I echo that directly?

Comment: So how can I get this kind of answer `13:00 (hh:mm)`?

Comment: echo $diff->h,':',$diff->i

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Function:

```
function date_difference ($date1, $date2) {
    $all = round((strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1)) / 60);
    $h = floor($all / 60);
    $m = $all - ($h * 60);
    return $h.":".$m;
}
```

Calling the function:

```
$result = date_difference($log_in, $log_out));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use like `DateTime` class of PHP as

**PHP>5.4**

```
$date = (new DateTime($log_in))->diff(new DateTime($log_out));
echo $date->format('%H:%I');//13:00
```

**PHP<5.4**

```
$in = new DateTime($log_in);
$out = new DateTime($log_out);
$date = $in->diff($out);
echo $date->format('%H:%I');
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/rrNSK)

Answer (score -1):

```
$log_in = "2015-9-16 07:00:00";
$log_out = "2015-9-16 20:00:00";
$da = explode(" ",$log_in);
$do = explode(" ",$log_out);
$new1 = explode(":",$da[1]);
$new2 = explode(":",$do[1]);
$result4 = $new2[0]-$new1[0];
echo $result4," h";
```

Comment: this is wrong, because it does take into account date, just hour and minute